# Telegram bot creating survey (poll)

Tags: python, post, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

how do i create automatic polls on telegram with python? I need to create a poll every 3 days and I need to automate this task. Is it possible to do this with a telegram robot or via script? I can't create a vote with my robots.

I know it is possible to send messages by the robot with the following code:

```
import telegram
bot = telegram.Bot(token='104014195************dew')

bot.sendMessage(-3251xx743, 'hello')
```

or by post method:

https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#message

but I can't do it that way.

My question is how to make a poll with post method or by python

I need an example code as there is not much information on the internet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you has tag `python-telegram-bot`, I guess you are using this library:

https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot

In this case you should use this method to send a poll:

https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.bot.html#telegram.Bot.sendPoll

Next step is to start your script regularly: you can do it by using `crontab`, for instance.